# fosuserbundle override template css

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm trying to override the FOSUserBundle Templates as show here:

https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_templates.md

I used the second method, I created my own bundle and put the templates in
myBundle/Resources/Views/Security/login.html.twig

and

myBundle/Resources/Views/Registration/register.html.twig.

both templates start with:

```
{% extends "::nologbase.html.twig" %}
```

where nologbase.html.twig is defined in app/Resourcer/views.

well, the first one (login) is correctly displayed but the second one (register) shows row html with no css.
I cleared the cache and I also tried to display only the extended template and compared the source code. it is exactly the same!

any idea?

thanks

Comment: What are the 2 URLs of the pages and to the CSS files? I suspect that in one case the URL to the CSS file is correct but the second URL indicates a directory (e.g. `.../users/...`) and the browser look for CSS files in this directory (which is virtual, it's only created by the routing rules).

Comment: I compared the source code for the two files, it is exactly the same. The only difference is that the overrwritten template register include a register_content.html.twig file.

Comment: OK I got it. the first one url is /login. the second one is /register/. the '/' at the end seems to cause a problem with the route. anyone know how not to force to to add the '/' at the end of the url?

Comment: well I solved this way: 1) in the routing file in my bundle I deleted the row prefix: /register. 2) in routing/registration.xml in FOSUserBundle I added the prefix for every route. 
If anyone know a better solution please let me know, usually I prefer not to modify the code in FOSUSerBundle. thanks!

Comment: What is the URL of the CSS file in the HTML rendered pages?

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

Comment: This relative path explains why the CSS is missing with the second URL. Please add the code that generate this CSS path in your question. The [assetic](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html) should generate working URLs, independently of the routing rules.

Comment: good. I changed to /assets/css/bootstrap.min.css and it works! thanks you

Comment: You mean you hard-coded the path to the file? The assetic can manage URLs in dev and prod modes automatically.